# Connection useFormik and useState is not updating the input field value

Tags: react-hooks, formik

**Task**: I'm trying to change the value of the input field using user-friendly button with. In other words to change the value of the field I don't use the input/select and other tags intended for this.

To be more precise, I'm making an online store with an administrative panel and creating the form to create a category(product categories, such as clothing, electronics and others). And each category has a `ParentId`(0 - if the first parent or some other value if the child category). I made the catalog button the same is in absolutely every online store and want to link this logic with the creation of a new category.
In the expanded categories menu, select a category, and the parent ID of this category will be shown in the text field. Like, I will select "Clothes and shoes" as the parent category, and a value will be placed in the text field, for example, 8 (the parent ID of the category "Clothes and Shoes")

**My approach**: I create one state field and change this one when I click on the one of the menu items. Menu items open when I click on the button.

```js
import React, {FC, useState} from "react";
import {Box, Button, Stack, SxProps, TextField} from "@mui/material";
import {useFormik} from "formik";

// own modules
import Catalog from "../catalog/Catalog"; 

const CreateCategory: FC = (sx?: SxProps) => {
    const [parentId, setParentId] = useState<number>(0);

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            name: "",
            label: "",
            parentId: parentId
        },
        onSubmit: (values, {setSubmitting}) => {
            console.log("values: ", values); // value of the parentId doesn't change on submit
            // ...other code...
            setSubmitting(false);
        }
    });

    console.log("parentId: ", parentId); // but value of the parentId in the state change properly
    return (
        <Box
            sx={{
                display: "grid",
                justifyContent: "flex-start",
                gridTemplateColumns: "1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr",
                gap: "2rem",
                "> *": {
                    gridColumn: "span 2"
                },
                ...sx
            }}
            component="form"
            onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
        >
            <TextField
                error={!!(formik.errors.name && formik.touched.name)}
                name="name"
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.name}
                label="Name (technical - in Latin)"
                variant="outlined"
                helperText={formik.errors.name}
            />
            <TextField
                error={!!(formik.errors.label && formik.touched.label)}
                name="label"
                onChange={formik.handleChange}
                value={formik.values.label}
                label="label(for users)"
                variant="outlined"
                helperText={formik.errors.label}
            />
            <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
                <TextField
                    sx={{flexGrow: 1}}
                    error={!!(formik.errors.parentId && formik.touched.parentId)}
                    name="parentId"
                    value={parentId}
                    label="parentId"
                    variant="outlined"
                    helperText={formik.errors.parentId}
                />
                <Catalog onClickOverload={setParentId} /> {/*custom catalog button*/}
                <Button
                    sx={{height: "100%", width: "max-content"}}
                    onClick={() => setParentId(0)} // you can change this value(0 to 10, example) to check, that initial value(0) doesn't change in the formik values
                >
                    Set parent (0)
                </Button>
            </Stack>
            <Button
                sx={{gridColumnStart: 2, gridColumnEnd: 4}}
                type="submit"
                disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
                variant="outlined">
                Create
            </Button>
        </Box>
    )
}

export default CreateCategory;
```

I can't figure out what to try, because the value of the state change but not the parentId value of the formik. I'm at a dead end. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no need to use useState in this case. It turned out that it was possible to use the following construction:

```js
formik.setFieldValue(nameField, value);
```

And when you need to change the value in the some custom way - you can use this one.